# How do get data from postgres tables and store it in a file as insert query programmatically from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I need help in understanding if there is a way to save the data present in the tables in Postgres database into a file, i want to do it through C# code.

I have around 4 tables and all the data present in each of these table should put inside one file as inser t statements.

Thanks in advance for the help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly possible. Access https://www.npgsql.org/. Using this you can connect to PostgreSQL and retrieve data from there. After you can iterate each as you like and create your insert statements.